# Matching operator only with an regex

Tags: regex, pcre

With this [example](http://regex101.com/r/bY7gL5/2), I am trying to only match operators in C-like code in order to add a space before and after it

For instance `a+b` should become `a + b` but `a + b` shouldn't become `a  +  b`. The other tricky thing is I shouldn't add a space in case of negative numbers like `-2`. Of course I need to be aware of all the exceptions like the text in comments like `// work-around`.

Here's the regex that I'm working on:

```
(?!= |=|&|\||%)(\+|-)(?! |=|\1)
```

Unfortunately the negative-lookaround doesn't work as expected. How can I fix it?

Comment: There can be many edge cases like `a/=5` or `a++` etc. I think you need clarify all those cases in question.

Comment: Once you do the replace, you can do a diff and go through what changed to try to catch any exceptions you missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just to help your regex a little.
The first (negative) lookahead, should be a (negative) lookbehind.

I don't think this is going to help with parsing math symbols though.

http://regex101.com/r/lX3aF6/1

```
 # (?<!=[ ])(?<![=&|%])(\+|-)(?!\1|[ =])

 (?<! = [ ] )
 (?<! [=&|%] )
 ( \+ | - )
 (?! \1 | [ =] )
```